# How to tell if a project is SOAP or REST in SoapUI

Tags: rest, soap, soapui

While I am testing a bunch of APIs inside SoapUI, I have hard time to find out whether my project is SOAP or REST. Is this information hidden somewhere inside a project once it is created? I tried clicking around, viewing Project Properties, but couldn't find it....

[image: Screenshot of my SOAPUI project]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green icons on the endpoint indicate a SOAP project. A REST endpoint has a blue icon.

It is quite possible that one project can have **both** SOAP and REST endpoints. That is why *"SOAP project"* or *"REST project"* is not stored anywhere, because it is meaningless. If you expand any of the methods under the endpoint, you will see additional icons that will say any of SOAP, GET, POST, etc. depending on what kind of method that is.